# SlashCommands not showing up

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I just finished my bot and wanted to invite it to another server to test it out.

However, when I typed / no commands showed up.

When I invited the bot I enabled application.commands so I can use the slashcommands but it still did not work. My bot also has a global slashcommand handler so it should normally work right?

I don't know if the handler code is needed but I'll still add it here in case you do need it:

```js
const { Perms } = require('../Validation/Permissions');
const { Client } = require('discord.js');

/**
 * @param {Client} client
 */

module.exports = async (client, PG, Ascii) => {
    const Table = new Ascii("Command Loaded");

    CommandsArray = [];

    (await PG(`${process.cwd()}/Commands/*/*.js`)).map(async (file) => {
        const command = require(file);

        if(!command.name)
        return Table.addRow(file.split("/")[7], "⛔ FAILED", "Missing a name.")

        if(command.type !== "USER" && !command.description)
        return Table.addRow(command.name, "⛔ FAILED", "Missing a description.")

        if(command.permission){
            if(Perms.includes(command.permission))
            command.defaultPermission = false;
            else
            return Table.addRow(command.name, "⛔ FAILED", "Permission is invalid.")
        }

        client.commands.set(command.name, command);
        CommandsArray.push(command);

        await Table.addRow(command.name, "✅ SUCCESSFUL");
    });

    

    console.log(Table.toString());

    // PERMISSIONS CHECK //

    client.on("ready", async () =>{
        client.guilds.cache.forEach((g) => {
            g.commands.set(CommandsArray).then(async (command) =>{
                const Roles = (commandName) => {
                    const cmdPerms = CommandsArray.find((c) => c.name === commandName).permission;
                if(!cmdPerms) return null;
    
                return g.roles.cache.filter((r) => r.permissions.has(cmdPerms) && !r.managed).first(10);
                }
    
                const fullPermissions = command.reduce((accumulator, r) =>{ 
                    const roles = Roles(r.name);
                    if(!roles) return accumulator;
    
                    const permissions = roles.reduce((a, r) =>{
                        return [...a, {id: r.id, type: "ROLE", permission:true}]
                    }, []);
    
                    return [...accumulator, {id: r.id, permissions}]
                }, []);
    
                await g.commands.permissions.set({ fullPermissions });
    
            });
        })
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to register the command first, which is essentially creating the command within Discord. Follow [the guide](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/creating-commands.html) to get it set up. And to clarify, you only register the command once, if that isn't obvious.

You can use Postman to create/edit the commands if you are comfortable with it.